# list with different behavior in python

Tags: python, list, types

When I try to print the range, I use the following:

```
list_test = list(range(5))
print(list_test) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But when I tried to do this:

```
list_test_2 = [range(5)]

print(list_test_2) # [range(0, 5)]
```

As we can see, the result is diferent but `list_test` and `list_test_2` are the same type.

```
list_test = list(range(5))
list_test_2 = [range(5)]

print(type(list_test))      # <class 'list'>
print(type(list_test_2))    # <class 'list'>
```

So, why the print have a diferent result? Behavior of the same type delivers different results?

Comment: A `range` object in python is lazily evaluated, i.e., it isn't made into a list unless you explicitly tell python to evaluate it into a list with the list constructor `list()` as opposed to just putting it in a list with `[]`

Comment: The first list contains five elements, which are ints. The second list contains one element, which is a range object. Lists with different lengths and different contents are different.

Comment: Ok, so `[range (5)]` is a list with one element and `list (range (5))` is a list too but with more elements. That is why both are lists but different. Thanks, I was very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion in here is because of that range is not an normal function. When you are calling range(5), it is not returning 1,2,3,4,5. It is returning a generator object.  These may be a bit hard for you. Notice that **[ ] is creating a list with objects inside it** , and **list function is converting argument to list**. So lets look that:

```py
range(5) == [1,2,3,4,5] # False
list(range(5)) == [range(5)] # False

my_list = list(range(5)) # in fact, range(5) is an object like 1 or "a", but you converting it to list. range(5) is converting to list as [1,2,3,4,5]
print(my_list)
>>> [1,2,3,4,5]
print(len(my_list))
>>> 5

other_list = [range(5)] # now , as i said range(5) is an object like 1 or "a". So it is the first and only one component of other_list
print(my_list)
>>> [range(5)]
print(len(my_list))
>>> 1
print(my_list[0])
>>> range(5)
print(list(my_list[0])) # but when we convert range(5) to list again, the result is same
>>> [1,2,3,4,5]

## this is the bonus:
print(type(range(5)))
>>> <class 'range'> # not a list
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are list type.
1st one is list of int and the next one is a list of list, but its still a list with a single object.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5] // type list with 5 elements
list2 = [[1,2,3,4,5]] // type list with 1 element
list3 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [4,5,6,7,8]] // type list with 2 elements
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example to help explain the difference between `list` and `[]`.  The first, `list`, is a function that takes a sequence and returns a list containing the elements of the sequence, while the latter allows you to define a list literal in your code with multiple elements. Take for example creating a list with multiple items:

```
myNestedList = ["string", 0, range(5), [], tuple(), dict()]
print(myList)
# ['string', 0, range(0, 5), [], (), {}]

# Notice that `list` only takes one argument so the following is not valid
# list("string, 0, range(5)]

# list takes the elements of and `iterable` and returns a list containing those elements :
print(list("a string"))
# ['a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
print(list({1, 2, 3, 4}))
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list(["a", "list", "of", "string"]))
# ['a', 'list', 'of', 'string']
```

Answer (score 1):

Results are different because `[]` is not converting `range(5)` into list but creating new list where `range(5)` is it's first and only element.

- `[]` is so called "list literal" and creates new list which contains content written inside it (empty if no content given)
- `list()` in other hand is function - list factory to be specific. It creates new list based on content of `iterable` object given in parenthesis (empty if nothing given), in that case iterable object is result of`range(5)`

Both objects have same type `<class 'list'>` because in fact both are lists but first one (`[range(5)]`) is list that contains `generator object` returned by `range(5)` and second one (`list(range(5)`) is list of integers because function `list()` "consumed" generator object and included it's elements inside newly created list that it returned.

If you want to create list of integers from `range(5)` using list iteral `[]` you can use `[*range(5)]` where asterix operator (*) unpacks content of range into list.